# Get text between two symbols in R

Tags: r

This may sound like a duplicate question but I have spent the last hour looking for the answer and can't apply the other similar sounding questions' solutions to this problem.

I have a string of text and want to extract the text from between the second `_` and the `.`

The furthest I have got is extracting the text from between the first `_` and the `.` as you can see below.

```
library(stringr)
mytext<-"one_two_three.four"
stringr::str_extract(mytext, "(?<=_)(.+)(?=\\.)")
```

So the answer I want is `three` rather than the `two_three` my answer gives.

Would prefer to keep with the str_extract function, can anyone modify my attempt to get the desired answer?

Comment: your regex looks (backwards for the first underline) then (captures anything) then (looks forward for a dot).  If it's always going to be the second underline then you want that first set of brackets to be (backwards for an underline, any amount of other stuff, then an underline).  `(?<=_.+_)(.+)(?=\\.)`

Comment: I struggle with stringr sometimes, but `gsub(".*_.*_(.*)\\..*", "\\1", mytext)` works

Comment: ignore my suggestion - stringr likes the look behind to be bounded.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(mytext, "(?<=_)([^_]+)(?=\\.)")` would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Matt L. suggestion
gsub(".*_.*_(.*)\\..*", "\\1", mytext)
[1] "three"
```

Explanation:
`.*_` = any amount of anything then an underscore.
`.*_` = any amount of anything then an underscore.
`(.*)` = any amount of anything, and this is a capture group.
`\\.` = a full stop/period (".")
`.*` = any amount of anything
`"\\1"` = please return the contents of the first capture group.

```
# rawr suggestion
stringr::str_extract(mytext, "(?<=_)([^_]+)(?=\\.)")
[1] "three"
```

Explanation:
`(?<=_)` = positive look behind i.e. there should be an underscore before the captured group
`([^_]+)` = one or more non-underscore characters
`(?=\\.)` = positive look ahead i.e. there should be a full stop / period after the captured group

And as of `stringr` release 1.5.0 you can specify a capture group, so my suggestions:

```
# my suggestions:
stringr::str_extract(mytext, "(_.+_)(.+)(\\.)", group = 2)
[1] "three"
```

Explanation:
`(_.+_)` = group 1 is an underscore then one or more of anything then an underscore.
`(.+)` = group 2 is one or more anythings
`(\\.)` = group 3 is a full stop / period
`group = 2` = give me group 2 please

```
#or 
stringr::str_split_i(mytext, "_|\\.",3)
[1] "three"
```

Explanation:
split into chunks by cutting out anything matching `"_|\\."` = underscore or a full stop/period
`,3` = give me the third chunk.